# Convert WGS84 to Local Point

Tags: coordinate-system, wgs84, haversine, three-js

I have `WGS84 points` and I should convert to `local coordinates (x, y, z)` and plot in ThreeJs. I referred the below article and created a converted (refer code below)

Article: [Calculate distance, bearing and more between Latitude/Longitude points](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) :

Code: [WGS84 to Local Coordinate Converter](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-tw8sdh?file=index.ts)

```
function convertPoint(gpsPoint: GpsPoint, originPoint: GpsPoint): LocalPoint {
    // calculate distance between reference point and calibration Gps points
    const distanceInMeters = HaversineDistance.calculate(originPoint, gpsPoint);
    const bearingAngle = calculateBearing(originPoint, gpsPoint);
    const distance = distanceInMeters;
    const y = -(distance * Math.cos(bearingAngle));
    const x = distance * Math.sin(bearingAngle);
    const z = calculateZ(gpsPoint);
    return { x: x, y: y, z: z };
}
```

The result is not coming as expected.

The WGS84 is coming near to strait line. Find the screenshot below

[image: WGS84 Output]

But the converted local coordinates are not not strait line. it get curved.

[image: Local Coordinate - Top view]

[image: Local Coordinate - Side view]

In the code, the converted values having a big different. both x and y.

[image]

*Help me to figure out where it is going wrong.*

Comment: The article linked is about finding distances (among others) between lat/long values. Those formulas are not for converting to a local coordinate system.

Comment: @Mintx, Can you help me with the conversion? I should convert to Local coordinate and plot it in ThreeJS canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure it out the problems. There were two issues.

1. Math functions will take value in radians. But I passes it as degree.

[image]

2. While calculating the bearing, the angle was not converted back degree and normalized.

[image]

The code is updated in the main post as well as find the code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-tw8sdh?file=index.ts).

Answer (score 0):

You could convert WGS84 to ECEF coordinates, then choose a ref point (should get a matrix 4x4) to convert to ENU coordinates.

But WGS84->ECEF is costly, you may directly use mapbox/cheap-ruler to convert WGS84 to ENU (kind of).

Comment: My implementation: https://github.com/cubao/headers/blob/24843da08f9d75813d702fa6cee046732a49606f/include/cubao/crs_transform.hpp#L226-L247